# What is solution for $y=|x-2|-2|x|$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am studying calculus book, and author there provides steps for getting solution of the equation

$$y = \sqrt{(x^2 - 4x + 4)} - 2|x|$$

, that, according to the author is (I do not know how to make brackets, so I combine solution just with $AND$)

$$y = x + 2, for \space x\le0 \space \space AND \space \space -3x+2, for\space 0<x\le2\space \space AND \space -x-2 \space for \space x > 2 \space _{(A)}$$

But, after solving it on my own, I get $\le$ in other place, and have $≥$:

$$y = x + 2, for \space x<0 \space \space AND \space \space -3x+2, for \space 0\le x < 2\space \space AND \space -x-2 \space for \space x ≥ 2 \space _{(B)}$$

How do I solve it:

$$y = \sqrt{(x-2)^2}-2|x| \space_{(1)}$$
$$y = |x-2|-2|x| \space_{(2)}$$
$$|x-2| = x-2, if \space x-2 ≥ 0 \space AND -x-2, if \space x-2<0 \space_{(3)}$$
$$|x| = x, if \space x ≥ 0 \space AND -x, if \space x<0 \space_{(4)}$$

And from $(3)$ and $(4)$ I get $(B)$, since there are 3 cases:

1. When $x$ is higher (or equal) than $2$ and hence higher (or equal) than zero, so $y=x-2 - 2x=-2-x$
2. When $x$ is not higher or equal than $2$, but still higher or equal than zero, so $y=-x+2-2x=2-3x$
3. And when $x$ less then zero, hence not higher or equal $2$, so $y = -x+2+2x=2+x$

My questions:

1. Is it a mistake in the book?
2. When I was solving first time, I was confused, trying to apply condition of the $|x|=-x, if\space x<0$ to the $|x-2|$, so there was not just $|x-2|=-x+2, if \space x<2$, but $|x-2|=-(-x)+2=x+2, if\space x<0 \space AND \space |x-2|=-x+2, if \space 0\le x<2$. It was wrong, because $|x|$ is not for all $x$ occurrences in the expression, as well as $|x-2|$ is not for all $x-2$, occurrences right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solutions are equivalent. At $x=2, -2-x = -3x+2$ and at $x=0, x+2 = -3x+2$. Meaning the change in the location of the equality cases does not change the answer.

Comment: Hmm, this is true, but actually, those examples end purpose was to plot functions. I am wondering currently, but it is seems, like the graph will not be changed (I am trying to imagine infinitely small closest interval to ${2}$, for example)

Comment: They won't be changed, the only difference between these plots would be the exact location of the 2 equality points (it's neighborhood is unnafected), and we already estabilished those don't move.